# How to check if all opened threading processes are finished?

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to implement some threading in my code, and it seemed at first that it was working fine. After checking my results, I have noticed that the code seems not to wait for the threads to be finished, but instead as long as they start, it continues with the rest of the code.

```
    def start_local_process(pair):
        try:
            name = 'name'
            some_other_function(name)
        except:
            print("Failed")

    print("Starting a total of %d threading processes." %len(some_list))
    for element in some_list:
        t= Thread(target=start_local_process, args=(pair,))
        t.start()
    print("Closed all threading processes for " + element + "!")
```

I can see that it does start a thread process for each element in some_list, which exactly what I want -parallel execution for each element. But, I get the last output message immediately after starting them, what I would prefer is, if it would wait for them to finish and then so print a message that they are finished. Is there a way to do it ?

**UPDATE:**
So, here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067786/checking-on-a-thread-remove-from-list) where part of the solution was given. The function that answers if a thread is still active is *.isAlive()*

With this function I could know if a thread is still active or not, but what would be a neat way of rechecking the same thing until all of the functions return TRUE?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067786/checking-on-a-thread-remove-from-list)?

Comment: I don't know how I did not came across that post.

Comment: @xbound please check update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you're saving your threads to list, you can do the following thing to check if all your threads finished the work:

```py
finished = all(not thread.is_alive() for thread in thread_list)
while not finished:
    finished = all(not thread.is_alive() for thread in thread_list)
print('All task finished...')
```

Comment: do you think a sleep()  command will interfere with the threads ? I wouldnt want it to keep asking if they are done, it should go on a interval..

Comment: you can use `time.sleep` although I'm not entirely sure how your program will behave. Python itself does not support `parallelism`. In reality only one thread is executed at the time. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92928/time-sleep-sleeps-thread-or-process) SO thread it seems like it should not be a problem.